# how can I create a folder at c:\ using Paths(not File)?

Tags: java, nio

```
Path myFile = Paths.get("c:").resolve("folderOne").resolve("filename.txt");
```

Output:
this creates the folderOne in the folder that the program runs but not at c:\ 
as hoped.

Comment: Does `...get("c:\")...` work?

Comment: are you using Java 9 or later ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name most likely, it won't... But `...get("c:\\")...` could work.

Comment: @davidxxx i'm using Java8.

Answer (score 2):

### The fix

Use a slash or a backslash after the drive name:

```
    final Path path = Paths.get("c:/").resolve("folderOne").resolve("filename.txt");
    Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
```

Note that a slash (`c:/`) works fine on Windows. A backslash works as well: `Paths.get("c:\\")`.

Note also that `Paths.get()` and `Path.resolve()` do **not** create directories by themselves. You can use `Files.createDirectories()` to do the job.

---

### Parsing the whole path with `Paths.get()`

If the path is fixed, you can parse it with `Paths.get()` directly — no need to call `.resolve()`:

```
    final Path path = Paths.get("c:/folderOne/filename.txt");
```

Again, both slashes and backslashes work on Windows.

---

### Drive-relative paths

`C:`, without (back)slashes creates a `DRIVE_RELATIVE` path — meaning that the path starts from the current folder on the given drive. A citation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats

> `C:Projects\apilibrary\apilibrary.sln`    A relative path *from the current directory* of the `C:` drive.

You can see this by converting to absolute path:

```
System.out.println(
    Paths.get("c:").resolve("folderOne").resolve("filename.txt")
        .toAbsolutePath()
);
```

---

Links:

- Java Windows path parsing: https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPathParser.java#L136

Comment: With such nice details, I miss `Paths.get("c:/folderOne/filename.txt");` or the comma version `Paths.get("c:/", folderOne", "filename.txt");` (whoever wants to use the latter)

Comment: @JoopEggen, thanks for the hint. Added `Paths.get(<full-path>)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Shesterov.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html) this would be how you create a directory in your case.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\folderOne");
Files.createDirectories(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import the following in your class:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

then you can use:

```
Path path = Paths.get("D:\\directoryName"); Files.createDirectories(path);
```

You also need to surround your code with a try-catch block OR you can add throws IOException like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
..
}
```